# Have a TableView and ListView take up the entire width of the screen

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, tableview

I've got the following XML for a layout on Android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <!--  Select building row  -->
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            style="@style/Default"
            android:layout_width="200px"
            android:text="Gebouw:"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/buildingSpinner"
            style="@style/Default"
            android:layout_width="300px"/>

    </TableRow>
    <!--  Select section row -->
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            style="@style/Default"
            android:layout_width="200px"
            android:text="Verdieping:"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/SectionSpinner"
            style="@style/Default"
            android:layout_width="300px"/>

    </TableRow>
    <!--  Select room row -->
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="300px"
            android:layout_margin="4px"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:background="#BBBBBB">

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/roomsList"
                    style="@style/Default"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="2px"
                    android:background="#EEEEEE"/>

                </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>
    <!--  Buttons row -->
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/selectedRoomText"
            style="@style/Default"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:text=""/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCreateChecklistForRoom"
            style="@style/Default"
            android:text="OK"/>

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

I'm trying to have the TableView and the ListView to take up the entire width of the screen, but I can't seem to get it working.

That said, I'd also like the ListView to take up all the remaining vertical space after the other elements have been rendered.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Mind to format your xml? It's nearly unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `TableRow` that contains `ListView` to this one:

```
<TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1">
- 

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="4px"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:background="#BBBBBB" android:layout_weight="1">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/roomsList"
                style="@style/Default"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2px"
                android:background="#EEEEEE"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
```

And I didn't get why do you need that `LinearLayout` inside. It can be removed with attributes moved to either its parent or its child

Comment: I added the linearlayout inside to create a border for the listview, couldn't figure out any other way (ps, I come from a XAML background)

Comment: So the example you have given, does make the LinearLayout use up all the remaining height, but the ListView shrinks and grows within it. More of the horizontal space is used now, but I still have a large unused space on the right

Comment: Updating the layout_height of the ListView to fill_parent solved the vertical issue